# How is it possible to duplicate HTTP headers?

Tags: django, http, nginx

I am running Django with the help of Gunicorn behind Nginx. I was adding some headers to the response using Nginx but then I decided to write middleware in Django which will do the same.

I was adding some values to the header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.
I added the middleware but forgot to remove the Nginx conf which was adding the headers. So, both the layers ended up adding headers. I later checked out the response in the browser which actually surprised me.

Here is the screenshot of the response,

[image: Response Headers]

So that brings me to the question, how is this possible?

Is Django's response a *different* object and Nginx's response different?
What exactly is the structure of the response object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP headers aren't objects, really. Best to think of them as key-value pairs, and nothing else. It's quite possible having duplicate headers and header values.

Why this is happening is simply based on specific directives (server) or code you use to set the headers and where in the request processing those header additions take place.

If you add a header in your backend app (Django, but really can be anything, like PHP), then use `add_header` for that same header in NGINX, you will have duplicate headers.

Simply because `add_header` does not look into the headers received from upstream (your app), then just blindly adds the one you specify in its configuration.

If you want to have a "set" behavior, then avoid duplicate headers altogether, then you want to use a third party module, [headers more](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/)

This will give you some additional directives to ensure the behavior you expect, e.g. `more_set_headers`.
At a slight performance impact though, because the `set` behvaior implies having to search existing headers from the backend first, then overwirting them.

Comment: yeah, it was a surprise that it worked this way. Also, `PWA` apps stopped working as they were not able to process the duplicate headers. That really messed things up.